# Using powershell to move sub-folder contents up one level; different parent folders

Tags: powershell, command-line, directory-structure, posh-git

I've looked through various questions on SO but can't get the script to work. New to Powershell and I'm sure this easy - any help would be great

I have a directory structure of 170 folders:

```
    G:\Data\ 
            folder1\
                     DCIM1\*jpgs
                     DCIM2\*jpgs

            folder2\
                     DCIM1\*jpgs
                     DCIM2\*jpgs
```

I would like to move all the jpgs from each DCIM subfolder into the parent folder one level up:

```
      G:\Data\ 
            folder1\*jpgs         
            folder2\*jpgs
```

Each parent folder has a different name, and potentially differently named DCIM subfolders, but all the jpgs are named with their folder prefix (e.g., DCIM1_001.jpg).

I have tried Powershell:

```
G:\> $files = Get-ChildItem "G:\data"
>> Get-ChildItem $files | Move-Item -Destination { $_.Directory.Parent.FullName }
>> $files | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

but get a destination is null error. I have tried a wildcard too:

```
 G:\> $files = Get-ChildItem "G:\data\*"
    >> Get-ChildItem $files | Move-Item -Destination { $_.Directory.Parent.FullName }
    >> $files | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

But I take it I have that completely wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Split-Path` to get the parent directory:

```
$JPGs = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\brief\datefolder" -Recurse -Filter "*.jpg"
    foreach ($JPG in $JPGs) {

        $Parent_Directory = Split-Path -Path $JPG.FullName -Parent
        $Destination_Path = Split-Path -Path $Parent_Directory -Parent
        
        Move-Item -Path $JPG.FullName -Destination $Destination_Path
            if ($null -eq (Get-ChildItem -Path $Parent_Directory)) {

                Remove-Item -Path $Parent_Directory

            }
    }
```

It's just a means of assigning it to a variable and moving along the line.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. Is there a way to add -Removeitem to this to delete the now empty subfolders?

Comment: Yup, see edit. The parent directory path is already in a variable so you can reference it when calling `Remove-Item`. Just remove the `#`.

Comment: This call for Remove-Item looks like it moved the first file in the subfolder (e.g., DCIM1_001.jpg, from DCIM1 to folder1) but then removed the subfolder and threw errors for all the remaining .jpgs in the subfolder that's not there anymore. It's okay if I need to manually delete the empty subfolders after moving the .jpgs?

Comment: See edit, pardon my mistake, an `if` condition can fix that.

Comment: This worked perfect - thanks again, hours of work saved!

Comment: No, worries. Anytime!:)