# Copy specific file types from multiple sources to multiple destinations using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure for example like this

```
- folder1
  - folderA
  - folderB
    - data
      - data.txt
      - data1.txt
- folder2
  - folderA
  - folderB
    - data
      - data.txt
      - data1.txt
```

I want the files (in this example 'file1.txt' 'file2.txt') to be copied and placed outside the folder and delete the folder the files were in like in the example below.

```
- folder1
  - folderA
  - folderB
    - data.txt
    - data1.txt
- folder2
  - folderA
  - folderB
    - data.txt
    - data1.txt
```

This is what I was able to put together.

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -r -Filter "*.txt" | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item ($_.FullName) -Destination '.' -r}
```

Using this I could copy the files but not to the destination I intended to. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: pretty sure my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67845538/14903754) is what you're after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using powershell to move sub-folder contents up one level; different parent folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845442/using-powershell-to-move-sub-folder-contents-up-one-level-different-parent-fold)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -r -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object { Move-Item ($_.FullName) -Destination ($_.Fullname -replace '\\data') -Confirm:$false }
```

I assume you wanted to move the files, according to your examples. And the new path is just 1 level up from the current path. Many ways to accomplish this, and mine above is not the most PowerShell-y, but I wanted to keep the complexity on-par with your case.

EDIT1:
You'll have to futz around with it if it doesn't work for you. Try printing the values when it fails like this:

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -r -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Fullname -replace '\\data'
    Write-Debug "Path not found: $($newpath)" -Debug:(-not (Test-Path $newpath))
    Copy-Item ($_.FullName) -Destination $newName -WhatIf
}
```

Added the `-WhatIf` so you can give it a test run. When the debug is tripped by a bad path name, `[S]USPEND` the command and inspect the variables, try different. Type `exit` and choose `[H]ALT` to get back to your prompt.

You might have a better debugging method, but that is what works for me.

This might work better, actually:

```
Get-ChildItem '.' -r -Filter "*.txt" |
ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.Fullname.Replace('\data')
    Write-Debug "Path not found: $($newpath)" -Debug:(-not (Test-Path $newpath))
    Copy-Item ($_.FullName) -Destination $newName -WhatIf
}
```

The `.Replace()` method takes a literal string, whereas the previous `-replace` operator takes a regex pattern.

Comment: i'd like to copy it so in case I want to leave the original untouched I can do that by taking out remove-item.. i tried this but for some reason, it's moving the files 2 levels up and also renaming the files using the folder name.

Comment: In EDIT1 I provided a couple more versions of the same with space for debugging. Try the my last  suggestion first, see if that works for you.